# Intermittent SQL Server Connection problems

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm performing a small load test on my Centos PHP server, which is connecting to SQL server on Windows 2003.  It's doing about 60 tps.

Around 1-10 out of every 1000 connections fail when I start up the load with a "cannot connect to the database."  However, I don't see any noticeable drop in performance.

Does anyone know how I might go about diagnosing this?

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, I'd install [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/).  That allows you to detect any network related issues.